# Use correct item in an array with time intervals

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match-all

I some text that looks like this:

> Vind vid marken
>    12-14UTC: Område E3a: N/2-5 knop, byar upp till 13 knop.
>    Område E2b: N/2-5 knop, byar upp till 14 knop.
>    Område E1a,E1b: NV-N/0-6 knop, byar upp till 15 knop.
>    Område E2a: N/1-6 knop, byar upp till 12 knop.
>
> 14-16UTC: Område E1b: N/2-6 knop, byar upp till 16 knop.
>    Område E3a: N/3-6 knop.
>    Område E2b: N/3-5 knop.
>    Område E2a: N/1-5 knop, byar upp till 12 knop.
>    Område E1a: N/0-6 knop, byar upp till 14 knop.
>
> 16-18UTC: Område E1b: N-NO/1-7 knop, byar upp till 15 knop.
>    Område E2a,E2b: N/0-4 knop, byar upp till 12 knop.
>    Område E1a: N-NO/3-8 knop, byar upp till 15 knop.
>    Område E3a: N-NO/1-6 knop, byar upp till 13 knop.
>
> 18-20UTC: Område E2b,E3a: N-NO/1-5 knop.
>    Område E1b,E2a: N-NO/0-5 knop, byar upp till 11 knop.
>    Område E1a: N-NO/1-7 knop.

My goal is to find the value of the correct location and time.
As you can see the text is deceived in times and in areas (for example E3a), and it repeats the same area in the next time interval.
With this regex: `preg_match_all("/(\d{2}-\d{2})UTC/", $text, $arr);`

I get this array:

```
array(2  
      0 =>  array(4  
          0 =>  12-14UTC  
          1 =>  14-16UTC  
          2 =>  16-18UTC  
          3 =>  18-20UTC  
      )  

      1 =>  array(4  
          0 =>  12-14  
          1 =>  14-16  
          2 =>  16-18  
          3 =>  18-20  
     )  
)
```

Right now the time is 14:52 UTC.
How do I... lets say echo `$arr[1][1]`, because I know the current time is between 14 and 16?
I need the regex to be either the way it is above, or at least maintain `$arr[0]` because I need that in the next regex pattern.

I'm stuck here because I can't figure out how to know what time interval it is I need in the next regex.

Comment: More globally what are you trying to achieve? What is your next regex?

Comment: This text is only a part of all of it, keep that in mind. But the next regex would be to capture one of the areas data at the correct time. Let's say E3a again, and depending on the time of the day I need to capture a different line of text. I'm typing on my phone right now so it's hard to write out the regex. But E3a is the first line if the time is between 12-14, then the second line in the next time interval. In short `[time interval].*E3a.*:(.*)\.` . Not sure that is entirely correct. But capture between : and . at correct time and area.

Comment: Instead of building a regex for E3a, 14:52, you should build a data structure with all your text records once and for all (basically a multidimensional array with, for instance, at the ground level the time interval as keys and at level 1 the locations as keys, with the remaining text as values). The time intervals seem to be always 2 hours from 00:00 until 22:00, you can even reduce the ground zero keys to the start hour. You only have to build a function that convert the requested time to an even slice of two hours (an even hour).

Comment: I see your point but out of all this text (and much more) I only need that one sentence (actually less than that, only the digits). I actually have no clue about the time intervals, they seem to be two hours all the time but I don't think they have to be that way. In the past this text looked different and it was easy to parse because the text layout had not changed in years, now they recently changed the layout with time intervals. I basically just need a way to parse out the correct numbers at the correct time and place those numbers in my code.(Fix the code that is now broken due to layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
preg_match_all("(\d{2})-(\d{2})UTC", $text, $arr);
```

That should return:

```
array(3
      0 =>  array(4
        0   =>  12-14UTC
        1   =>  14-16UTC
        2   =>  16-18UTC
        3   =>  18-20UTC
    )
  1 =>  array(4
        0   =>  12
        1   =>  14
        2   =>  16
        3   =>  18
    )
  2 =>  array(4
        0   =>  14
        1   =>  16
        2   =>  18
        3   =>  20
    )
)
```

From there you can use the values of array[1] and array[2] to compare against your current hour (using `date("G")`) either by iteration or a callback.

Since you're going to be pulling the time values from the regex, I would also recommend you sanitize and error check your inputs as best as possible as well using perhaps `intval()`.

Comment: In your example I could loop through `$arr[1]` backwards (3->0) and do `if (date("H") >= $arr[1][$i])`  then the first time it returns true should be the correct item in the array. So if I exit the loop $i should have the index value I can use in $arr[0].

Comment: You could check both arrays at once in your loop.  `if (date("H") >= $arr[1]  && date("H") < $arr[2])`. The only thing you should be mindful of is your date conditions. Your `if()` statement should handle where 14:10 UTC will fall (between 12-14 or 14-16).